# Why the multiple read commands giving me errors

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

```
#!/bin/bash
# your code goes here
echo "1.Addition 2.Subtraction 3.Multiplication 4.Division"
read n
echo "Enter the operends"
read a
read b
case $n in
"1") echo "$a+$b =`expr $a \ + $b`";;
"2") echo "$a-$b=`expr $a \ - $b`";;
"3") echo "$a*$b=`expr $a \ * $b`";;
"4") echo "$a/$b=`expr $a \ / $b`";;
esac
```

**Ther errors are**

```
expr: syntax error: unexpected argument ‘ +’
```

**Whent the input is**

> 1 1 1
> 1.Addition 2.Subtraction 3.Multiplication 4.Division
> Enter the operends
> 1+1 =
> this is the output

Comment: what shell are you running this under ... `sh`? `bash`? something else? (is there a shebang in the script file and if so what is it)? the terminator for a `case` clause is `;;` (double semicolon); the end of a `case` statement is `esac` (all lowercase); fix those couple issues, and update the question with your latest/fixed code and the new error message(s)

Comment: Run `dos2unix` on the script

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: FYI last edit completely changed the question that OP has

Comment: @markp-fuso i have done please check ......

Comment: @varunprasad You're getting confused about the argument syntax for the `expr` command. Don't bother, just use `$(( ))` instead, e.g. `echo "$a*$b=$(($a * $b))"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem you had were Windows line endings, `dos2unix` fixed that.

The second problem is that you don't need to escape operators in `expr` except for `*`, it should be:

```
"1") echo "$a+$b =`expr $a + $b`";;
"2") echo "$a-$b=`expr $a - $b`";;
"3") echo "$a*$b=`expr $a \* $b`";;
"4") echo "$a/$b=`expr $a / $b`";;
```

Now your script will run ok:

```
$ ./main.sh
1.Addition 2.Subtraction 3.Multiplication 4.Division
1
Enter the operends
2
3
2+3 =5
$ ./main.sh
1.Addition 2.Subtraction 3.Multiplication 4.Division
2
Enter the operends
5
2
5-2=3
```

BTW, there are plenty of things wrong with the script, you should always check your scripts with
[shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) and fix all errors it
reports.

Comment: Except you *do* need to escape (or quote) the `*` to keep it from expanding to a list of filenames (just be sure to escape the `*`, not the space before it as in the original).